# Is it possible to get the profile image in EWS Managed API?

Tags: angular, ews-managed-api

I have a Angular Application and try to get the profile image of a user via EWS.

I discover this https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api and its look good but i cant find any informations about pictures so far.

Cheers 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Angular in browser (chrome, safari etc.) it is not going to work due to Exchange limitation. it has to be browser like process where XHR supports unsecure CORS. You can do it in Cordova or in node js process. you can have a proxy running in node js or in asp.net official ews managed api.

if you happen to work on cordova/ionic etc, let me know in comment, I will update the answer.

Comment: there is a way to make this work in enterprise environment, if you are working on enterprise apps used internally, I can provide more info